# Treat initial numbers as argument to functions in minor mode

Tags: minor-mode, prefix-argument

Is it possible to treat typed numbers similar to universal argument `C-u 10 C-n`, but make it so that there is no need to type `C-u` in a minor mode? So only `10 C-n` would be needed to move 10 lines down and `C-n` to move 1 line down.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you can also use `C-1`, `C-2`, ..., instead of typing `C-u NUM` ...  E.g. `C-4 C-n` for four lines down.

Comment: ...which is essentially a solution: such sequences are all bound to `C-h f digit-argument`, so your minor mode map would simply bind the un-modified number keys to that as well.

Comment: Note that `M-0` to `M-9` are the reliable variants in a terminal (`C-0` to `C-9` may also work for GUI frames).  Both sets can be useful depending on what you are intending to type next, if you like to avoid switching between modifier keys.  Note also that for multi-digit numbers you only need the modifier key for the first digit -- after the first one, it's as if you'd used `C-u`.  e.g. `M-1 0 0 M-f` would move forward 100 words (as would `M-1 M-0 M-0 M-f`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course.  The canonical way to do that is to use `suppress-keymap` on your mode's keymap.  E.g.

```
(defvar my-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-keymap)))
    (suppress-keymap map)
    ...
    map))
```

In the unlikely case that you want to keep the self-inserting behavior of non-digits, then you should instead manually bind each digit to `digit-argument` as you apparently discovered in the mean time.

Comment: this is how I did it `(define-minor-mode nav-mode
  "Toggle Nav Mode"
  :init-value nil
  :lighter " Nav"
  :group 'nav
  :keymap (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
            (suppress-keymap map)
            (define-key map (kbd "1") (kbd "C-u 1"))
            map))`

Comment: I recommend you define the keymap in a separate `(defvar nav-mode-map ....)` instead of using the `:keymap` argument, but if it worked for you then it's all that matters.